# DataReader error - "no data exist for the row/column" - when data exists?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I need some help in understanding my error. I want to read data from table, however I get error such as "no data exist for the row/column". I dont understand it, since I actually have rows and columns in there. WinForms. Thanks!

```
    //this is how i insert data into table, works fine 
    public void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO tbl1(Name, LastName) VALUES (@Name, @LastName)", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", l1.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    //this is how i try to read data from the same table
    public void b2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:test.sdf");
       conn.Open();
       SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM  tbl1", conn);
       SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

       //error here
       string Name = reader.GetString(0);
       label.Text = Name;
    }
```

Comment: Please make sure to include *only* the relevant code next time (go ahead and remove the irrelevant code now); the method definition can also be removed as it doesn't apply to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your results' loading.

```
SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
   string Name = reader.GetString(0);
}
```

So you use the [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) method to iterate through the results. Or, if you just have one result then you can also use the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

```
string Name = reader.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: The key point is that `Read()` *must* be invoked once before results can be read from the reader - it starts initially positioned *before* the first result; e.g. `reader.Read(); string Name = reader.GetString(0);` would have been sufficient (assuming at least one row was returned).

Answer (score 1):

In this sequence

```
    SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO tbl1(Name, LastName) VALUES (@Name, @LastName)", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", l1.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You're not setting the 2nd parameter `@LastName` so it should have failed.  If you didn't previously have records in the table, you would have nothing to select from.

That, and the fact that you are not calling `reader.Read()`